BreezeJS throws a fixup error when attempting to save entities using many-to-many relations
I am attempting to update a stable Angular app which uses BreezeJS v1.7.2 to the latest v2.1.4.
After the update, I am seeing client-side errors when attempting to save entities that hold many-to-many relations.
The following code snippet reflects my attempt to create and save a new dependent entity, in a many-to-many relationship, together with its associated join entity. This code pattern was working correctly in Breeze v1.7.2:
const dependent = entityManager.createEntity('Dependent', {
    containerId: 113,       // An existing parent entity
    title: 'Test dependent entity'
});

const join = entityManager.createEntity('Join', {
    dependentId: dependent.id,
    principalId: 'ad3f84bb-ae38-4125-b73c-3cb5cbb88c04'     // An existing principal entity
});

await entityManager.saveChanges();

The save operation issues the following API request ...
{
    "entities": [{
            "ContainerId": 113,
            "Id": -1,
            "Title": "Test dependent entity",
            "__unmapped": {},
            "entityAspect": {
                "entityTypeName": "Dependent:#MyApp.Models",
                "defaultResourceName": "Dependents",
                "entityState": "Added",
                "originalValuesMap": {},
                "autoGeneratedKey": {
                    "propertyName": "Id",
                    "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
                }
            }
        }, {
            "DependentId": -1,
            "PrincipalId": "ad3f84bb-ae38-4125-b73c-3cb5cbb88c04",
            "entityAspect": {
                "entityTypeName": "Join:#MyApp.Models",
                "defaultResourceName": "Joins",
                "entityState": "Added",
                "originalValuesMap": {},
                "autoGeneratedKey": {
                    "propertyName": "DependentId",
                    "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "saveOptions": {}
}

... and receives the following response ...
{
    "$id": "1",
    "$type": "Breeze.Persistence.SaveResult, Breeze.Persistence",
    "Entities": [
        {
            "$id": "2",
            "$type": "MyApp.Models.Dependent, MyApp.Models",
            "ContainerId": 113,
            "Title": "Test dependent entity",
            "Id": 975
        },
        {
            "$id": "3",
            "$type": "MyApp.Models.Join, MyApp.Models",
            "DependentId": 975,
            "PrincipalId": "ad3f84bb-ae38-4125-b73c-3cb5cbb88c04"
        }
    ],
    "KeyMappings": [
        {
            "$id": "4",
            "$type": "Breeze.Persistence.KeyMapping, Breeze.Persistence",
            "EntityTypeName": "MyApp.Models.Dependent",
            "TempValue": -1,
            "RealValue": 975
        },
        {
            "$id": "5",
            "$type": "Breeze.Persistence.KeyMapping, Breeze.Persistence",
            "EntityTypeName": "MyApp.Models.Join",
            "TempValue": -1,
            "RealValue": 975
        }
    ],
    "DeletedKeys": []
}

The new dependent entity and its join entity are successfully added to the database, but the Breeze client throws an error when attempting to perform its fixup operation to resolve keys.
By setting a breakpoint in the Breeze code, I can see that function EntityGroup._fixupKey receives a tempValue of -1 and a realValue of 975, which corresponds to the  key mappings received from the server.
However, the following line in EntityGroup._fixupKey ...
let ix = this._indexMap[tempValue];
... is searching _indexMap for a value of -1, but this entry is missing. The only entry in _indexMap has a key of 975:::ad3f84bb-ae38-4125-b73c-3cb5cbb88c04, which suggests that, at the point where the error is thrown, the fixup has already been successfully applied.
I guess there's a mistake in the way I am initializing my join entity, but it's not clear what I should do differently. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Update
Looking more closely at the Breeze code, I can see that the complete fixup sequence for both the dependent entity and the join entity is performed by the following code line in function EntityGroup._fixupKey, which also includes the comment fks on related entities will automatically get updated by this as well:
entity.setProperty(keyPropName, realValue);

It therefore seems to me that the 2nd fixup operation (which is triggered by the 2nd key mapping in the server response data) is unnecessary. But I am still not clear what I need to do to prevent it from occurring.
Do I need to change my client-side implementation in some way, so as to exclude the join entity from fixup? Or is a server-side change necessary, to prevent it from sending the 2nd (redundant) key mapping entry?
Update 2
As requested by Steve Schmitt, here is the model metadata for the join entity. I have removed some entity properties that are unrelated to this issue:
{
    "shortName": "Join",
    "namespace": "MyApp.Models",
    "autoGeneratedKeyType": 0,
    "defaultResourceName": "Joins",
    "isComplexType": false,
    "dataProperties": [{
            "dataType": "Int32",
            "isPartOfKey": true,
            "isNullable": false,
            "nameOnServer": "DependentId",
            "validators": [{
                    "name": "required"
                }, {
                    "name": "int32"
                }
            ]
        }, {
            "dataType": "String",
            "isPartOfKey": true,
            "isNullable": false,
            "nameOnServer": "PrincipalId",
            "validators": [{
                    "name": "required"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "navigationProperties": [{
            "entityTypeName": "Dependent:#MyApp.Models",
            "isScalar": true,
            "associationName": "MyApp.Models.Join_MyApp.Models.Dependent_Dependent",
            "foreignKeyNamesOnServer": ["DependentId"],
            "nameOnServer": "Dependent",
            "validators": []
        }, {
            "entityTypeName": "Principal:#MyApp.Models",
            "isScalar": true,
            "associationName": "MyApp.Models.Join_PrincipalId_PrincipalId",
            "foreignKeyNamesOnServer": ["PrincipalId"],
            "nameOnServer": "Principal",
            "validators": []
        }
    ]
}

The two-part is defined in the model builder configuration, as follows, but I am wondering whether I need something extra to designate this as a many-to-many join entity?
    builder.HasKey(
        nameof(Join.Principal),
        nameof(Join.Dependent));


Just to be sure: you haven't changed the server version of Breeze at the same time?

Also, what is the actual error?

@SteveSchmitt Yes I have also updated the server to run Breeze.AspNetCore.NetCore v7.2.1 and Breeze.Persistence.EFCore v7.2.1. I assumed that the issue is caused by the client, since I am not seeing server-side exceptions, but I accept that the root cause could be in the data returned by the server. The client-side error message is "saveFail Error: Internal Error in key fixup - unable to locate entity" at entity-group.ts:174:13.

Would it be possible to run the new client against the old server (or vice-versa) to test whether it might be a server issue?

I'm not able to run the new client against the old server, because there are other changes that make them incompatible, but I have used Postman to simulate a client request against the old server, using the sample data above. The request is processed  without exceptions and the response data contains key mapping entries for both the dependent entity and the join entity. So, it seems to me that the server data has not changed; the client has changed the way it processes key mappings.

Update: I created a workaround, by using an Angular interceptor to modify SaveChanges server responses, by removing key mappings from known entity types that are implicitly fixed up as part of their parent entity fixup. This definitely solves the reported issue, but it is ugly and fragile. It would be great to know whether the errant Breeze behavior is attributable to a Breeze bug or some other mistake on my part.

One thing that strikes me as odd: the Join entity should have a two-part key, but the KeyMappings response from the server only has one of the keys specified.  What is the metadata definition for the Join entity?

I've updated my question to include the model metadata for the join entity. It does, indeed, appear to be missing the second part of the key. I've also included the model builder definition that specifies the two-part key, but there isn't any configuration that explicitly designates this entity type as a join entity. Might that be the cause of the problem?

What you've posted is just the metadata for the relation from Join to Dependent.  The metadata for the Join entity itself would start with "shortName": "Join", and then have dataProperties with "isPartOfKey": true.

Sorry for that, Steve. I've updated the question to include the complete metadata for the join entity. It seems to be complete with both of the required key parts, but I am curious whether you'll notice anything else that's suspicious.

You metadata looks correct to me.  I'm still not sure if the problem is in the server's KeyMapping response, or the client's handling of it.  I'll need to try to reproduce the problem.

Thanks. I created a separate GitHub issue at the same time as I posted this question. Please let me know if you need anything further from me.
